# How to inverse <li> selection using :not() and :contains()?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I want to make a live search with jQuery. Here's my code:

```
$("#searchInput").on("keyup", function () {
        var searchTerm = $("#searchInput").val();
        $('li:contains("' + searchTerm + '")').show().siblings(':not(li:contains("' + searchTerm + '"))').hide();
});
```

Showing `<li>` which contains "searched text" work properly but the second part (hiding the rest of the items) doesn't work completely.

How can I hide `<li>`s when I search for unrelated word?

Comment: why not just hide all li first and then show the ones that contain your search term - would be far more efficient - `$('li').hide().filter(':contains("' + searchTerm + '")').show()`

Comment: have you tried simplifying it with 

.siblings().hide()

https://api.jquery.com/siblings/

Comment: @ConfusedShark as internally jQuery iterates over all elements in a collection that would hide all other siblings, even if they do in fact contain the search term.

Comment: Thanks guys! You'are awesome!

Comment: @Pete Thanks so much man. It worked fine. If I had your brain ...

Comment: @Connum quite right, thats what happens when i dont test in a code snippet. Pete answer is the one to use

Comment: $("li").show().not($('li:contains("' + searchTerm + '")')).hide(); see my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [jQuery.not](http://api.jquery.com/not/)

**Solution 1**

```js
$("#searchInput").on("keyup", function() {
  var searchTerm = $("#searchInput").val();
  $("ul li").show().not($('li:contains("' + searchTerm + '")')).hide();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="searchInput" />
<ul>
<li>
  Hello
</li>
<li>
  World
</li>
<li>
  List 1
</li>
<li>
 Word
</li>
<li>
  Another Li
</li>
</ul>
```

You can use [jQuery filter](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) ( see below snippet)

**Solution 2**

```js
$("#searchInput").on("keyup", function() {
  var searchTerm = $("#searchInput").val();
  $("ul li").show().filter(function() {
    return $(this).text().indexOf(searchTerm) == -1
  }).hide();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="searchInput" />
<ul>
<li>
  Hello
</li>
<li>
  World
</li>
<li>
  List 1
</li>
<li>
 Word
</li>
<li>
  Another Li
</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Great answer! Instructive solutions, Hey man you are awesome! Apologize, I can't vote your answer yet.